# Brownie.exe not launching after successful install

Tags: python

I'm getting a fatal error when I try to load brownie. It installed without any errors so I'm confused as to what went wrong. The full error is:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\kenma\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe"  "C:\Users\kenma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\brownie.exe" ': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: So I was was looking to see if I was missing any files and it looks like c:\users\kenma\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe is missing. When I install python it creates a directory at c:/Python39. How do I get brownie to look there instead?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to restart your terminal after installing pipx.
Link: - https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html

Comment: Yeh, I tried that, even restarted my system. Could it be anything else?